# Can I have an auto-increment column shared by two layers?

Tags: qgis, sql, qfield

I have two layers, a "foo" points layer, and a "bar" polygon layer, each has a "foobar_n" column and a datetime column.

These are survey layers for use in QField, and the end result required is for the column "foobar_n" to be sequential based on when the point/polygon object was taken.

Currently I retroactively apply these numbers using a python script using the datetime column from each layer.

However is it possible to apply a `CASE WHEN` argument to the "foobar_n" columns in each layer so that I sequentially number as I survey?

The option to do this manually during survey is not practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. In your default value for foobar_n, use the following expression

```
Max(aggregate('foo','max', "foobar_n"), aggregate('bar','max', "foobar_n"),0)+1
```

aggregate() returns an aggregate value (e.g. max, count, sum etc) from features on the another layer.
The expression contains an aggregate() for each layer and the value zero, inside a Max() function. The 0 value is to accommodate the case where there are no features with values in foobar_n. I then add 1 to the result to get the next in sequence.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Aggregate! I will try this later today. Looks like the required solution, and update.

Comment: this was solution. Answer accepted.